# Javascript explode issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running an ajax query and returning JSON and one of the results is a field named `image.comment` e.g.

```
test~63~Dave Sanders~http://graph.facebook.com/998433599/picture?type=large~Dave Sanders~9 minutes ago
```

I'm using `~` as a separator

There maybe be multiple similar sets of data separated by `----` in `image.comment` so to parse the data and add it to the DOM i'm using:

```
if(image.comment){

        html += '<div class="msgs_holder'+image.list_id+'">';

        // split comment at ----        
        var comString = image.comment;
        var comArray = comString.split("----");

        var lengthArray = comArray.length,
        element = null;

        for (var i = 0; i < lengthArray; i++) {
            element = comArray[i];

            // split indiv comment at ~     
            var comUserString = element;
            var comUserArray = comUserString.split("~");

            html += '<div class="msgs_row"><div class="msgs_pic"><a href="/'+comUserArray[4]+'"><img src="'+comUserArray[3]+'"></a></div>';
            html += '<div class="msgs_comment"><a href="/'+comUserArray[4]+'" style="text-decoration:none;"><span class="msgs_name">'+comUserArray[2]+'</span></a> '+comUserArray[0]+'<br><span class="msgs_time" title="'+comUserArray[5]+'">'+comUserArray[5]+'</span></div></div>';

        }

        html += '</div>';

    }
```

But the page fails to load and firefox firebug tells me: `allocation size overflow`

This only happens on rows of the JSON where there is data in `comment` column

I suspect some maybe infinite looping but can't see it

I've checked the query and it runs fine so not that

Is this the best way to explode in js?

Any ideas?

**MORE INFO** The reason I'm doing it this way is it's a piece of a much bigger query. Images loaded to a page with comments under each image. So I'm loading the comments into a column to be parsed for display.

Example:

```
Image 1        Image 2        Image 3                       etc etc etc
hey                           i think its great!
hey back!                     me too
                              I'm not sure
```

**MORE INFO 2** This data is taken from a MySQL query e.g

```
select w.img_width, w.img_height, w.prod_pic_url as preview3,
        GROUP_CONCAT(ww.comment,'~', h.user_id,'~', h.name,'~', 
        h.live_prof_pic,'~', h.twovo_url,'~', time_ago(ww.dateadded) SEPARATOR '----') AS comment 
        from tableName where blah=blah
```

GROUP_CONCAT is the comments section mentioned above

So, to use JSON for data within data, is that possible? If so how?

Example returned data:

```
"preview3":"http:\/\/myurl.com\/wish_images\/production\/3578.jpg","comment":"test~63~Dave Sanders~http:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/Dave Sanders\/picture?type=large~Dave Sanders~39 minutes ago"},{"item_id":"3559","numComms":"0","numLikes":"0"... etc etc
```

Comment: Why don't you actually return JSON instead of a String?

Comment: because its nested in a much bigger query - think images with comments under them, therefore 1 to many, the comments are in the string linked to each image

Comment: So? Why does that matter? It will simplify your world on the javascript side and be less obtuse on the server side if you go with JSON. And you also won't have to deal with the annoying case where "Dave Sanders" decides to call himself "Dave~Sanders" instead.

Comment: How large is your data?

Comment: results e.g. image 1 comment 1, image 1 comment 2, image 2 comment 1, image 3 comment 1, image 4 comment 2 etc etc

Comment: You should be using JSON. You will not have any fun doing it this way.

Comment: @Jivings i'm getting that but its by far the best way - pls see comment above to see why doing it this way

Comment: That doesn't convince me. JSON is the best way.

Comment: I still don't get it. JSON can handle your one-to-many case.

Comment: @ChrisFarmer can you pls give example of what you mean? anyone, i appreacaite you all saying wrong way but help would be appreciated

Comment: You could start by eliminating the intermediate strings you're creating, like `comString = image.comment`, `element = comArray[i]`, `comUserString = element`. They may be taking too much memory.

Comment: Instead of using some arbitrarily delimited string, actually create a javascript object out of it: `{ label: 'test', id: 63, src: 'http://foo/image.jpg?bar=xxx' /* etc... */ }`

Comment: Why do you concatenate the data in the SQL query? Just fetch the columns normally and turn the resulting array into JSON. Seriously, there's no reason at all to not use JSON.

Comment: @Juhana Pls see question updates for reason for this

Comment: There's nothing there that would give any kind of explanation. If there's some reason you can't change the SQL query, at least you can explode the string into an array after the query.

Comment: @Juhana ??? Thats exactly what I'm doing isn't it? with var comArray = comString.split("----"); and then var comUserArray = comUserString.split("~"); If you mean change the query then how? Thats the whole question

Answer (score 6):

This isn't suited for a comment, so I'll try to write what I think people are saying with respect to using JSON instead of your strings:

This:

```
test~63~Dave Sanders~http://graph.facebook.com/998433599/picture?type=large~Dave Sanders~9 minutes ago
```

Could become this:

```
[
    {
        'name': 'test',
        'id': 63,
        'name': 'Dave Sanders',
        'url': 'http://graph.facebook.com/998433599/picture?type=large',
        'when': '9 minutes ago'
        // other properties
    },
    {
        // the next one
    },
    {
        // etc.
    }
]
```

It may look like more work, but you could use some JSON library for php (I'm guessing, since you use the term "explode") to build the JSON on the server.  Then your returned content is already in a form for your browser-based client app to use with no additional effort.  I find it hard to imagine that this will be more work in the end than what you're trying to do with the string manipulation, and JSON is likely to be less brittle.

Answer (score 2):

As per your updated question...

You can still use JSON for this. I think it might help you to read the [JSON specification](http://www.json.org/)

Adding to Chris Farmer's answer, JSON can be made of Arrays as well, so you can nest your comments in the response:

```
var response = [
  {
    'name': 'test',
    'id': 63,
    'name: 'Dave Sanders',
    'url': 'http://graph.facebook.com/998433599/picture?type=large',
    'comments' : [
       'comment1',
       'comment2',
       'comment3',
       ...
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

You can then loop through the comments like this:

```
// loop through the images
for ( var i = 0;  i < response.length; i++ ) {

    var image = response[i];

    // loop through the comments
    for ( var z = 0;  z < response.length; z++ ) { 
        var comment = image.comments[z];
        // insert HTML here.
    }
}
```

Do you see how much easier and less verbose this is than your current method?

Unfortunately to make this easier for yourself in the long run you **will** have to re-write your backend code. However, this will teach you the benefit and power of using JSON to transport information.

Comment: OK, will update question again, you're missing a level of exploding which I mentioned in update, also this data is contained within a mysql query, again will update - if I'm missing something here I'd love to know because I'm not getting what you're saying about converting a section of results to JSON

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Perhaps providing the backend code that is creating the String that needs exploding would be helpful.

Comment: Please see updated question, I appreciate your time, driving me insane!

Comment: Where is it being converted into that last snippet?

Comment: var comArray = comString.split("----"); and then var comUserArray = comUserString.split("~");