# using .get to add html before adding to DOM

Tags: jquery, dom

I am looping through JSON results to build a page before adding it the the DOM

Depending on what is in the looped results I may want to add the contents of another file but its not adding. I'm trying it in a logical way but often not right!

To test, the file `addme.php` contains one line which is `html += 'hello';`

```
var html = '';
var i=0, length=data.length, image;

for(; i<length; i++) {

image = data[i]; 

html += '<li>';
html += '<div id="holder'+image.itemID+'">';

if(image.comment){

$.get('/pages/includes/addme.php', { list_id:+image.list_id });

}

html += '<div class="row">'+image.comment+'</div>';
html += '</div>';
html += '</li>';

}
$('#display').append(html);
```

Can this be done? I know I can't use append as its not actually in the DOM yet at the point it needs adding

Comment: `$.get` is asynchronous. You sure you want to make request from loop ?

Comment: @phobos No, not sure - this is original question which i'm trying to do a diff way - tearing hair out! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485535/javascript-explode-issue

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15486224/1211980 is possibly the best solution for your problem. That'll introduce a little effort to from such json but it's surely worth and *proper* way to do it. Then you don't have to worry about how to parse it and all. Link also contains the code block how to parse it.

Comment: @phobos but the code is contained within json results already, it is one of the fields returned, is it possible to have json within json? I didn't think it was and if it is I wouldn't know how to convert it in there

Comment: can you post the json you are having right now ?

Comment: @phobos if you look at OP at bottom it shows the mysql query and then under is some of the json returned with the field 'comment' being the one which is the subject of the group_concat from the query - and the problem data